# Can a sink drain into a shower venting pipe?

Tags: sink, drain-waste-vent

I'm trying to add a sink next to an existing bathroom. Sink will be probably 3 feet from shower vent pipe. Floor is a concrete slab so all existing drains are underneath. I'd like to minimize busting thru concrete. The picture below is a pretty good representation of the existing piping, except for the pipe below grade that are probably running horizontally.

Can a sink drain/vent into a nearby shower vent pipe (e.g. connection in red on the picture)?

If this is not allowed, what's the best solution here?

[image: New sink drainage]

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a utility sink installed on the common wall of our garage and house. There was a vertical vent inside the wall near a bathroom and near the washer/dryer alcove. The plumber plumbed the drain into that vent saying that this was allowed by code *if* done in the right way. I didn't understand what would make it code compliant and would make it work properly, but he put it in and it has worked for 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enough slope. Also I would rather use a Y instead of a Tee.
If I am not mistaken, if the distance from the Sink trap to the drain (Vent) pipe is under four feet, you should be ok.